# Redshift: regexp to remove duplicates within column data

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I have the requirement to write a query in redshift database to remove the duplicates within column.

```
select regexp_replace('GiftCard,GiftCard',  '([^,]*)(,\2)+($|,)', '\2\3')
```

Expected results : `GiftCard`

obtained results: `GiftCard,GiftCard`

Basically, I want to search for the value in the column and remove if repeated.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Does the data always looks like <string1>,<string1> ?? In what other formats do you see data for this column?

Comment: Yes, the data will be always string1, string2,

Comment: I meant to ask if the data has columns like (string1,string1) always or (string1,string2) (string1,string1). Out of which you want to find only the values which are duplicated and get only one string as output?

Comment: I think a python UDF may work well here.

Comment: @hadooper . it will be of any value and any number of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this can be done using just a regex query but as Jon mentioned a UDF will work quite well.

Just split the text on the comma, create a set of unique words, and return it in some format. The function would be something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_unique_words (s text)
    RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
    return ','.join(set(s.split(',')))
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Example usage:

```
> select f_unique_words('GiftCard,GiftCard');
[GiftCard]
> select f_unique_words('GiftCard,Cat,Dog,Cat,Cat,Frog,frog,GiftCard');
[frog,GiftCard,Dog,Frog,Cat]
```

It does depend on you having appropriate access rights to the cluster. To create the function, also make sure you have USAGE granted on language 'plpythonu' for your user.

As a side note if you want a case insensitive version of this that doesn't put all your output in lower case, this would do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_unique_words_ignore_case (s text)
    RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
    wordset = set(s.split(','))
    return ','.join(item for item in wordset if item.istitle() or item.title() not in wordset)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Example usage:

```
> select f_unique_words_ignore_case('GiftCard,Cat,Dog,Cat,Cat,Frog,frog,GiftCard');
[GiftCard,Dog,Frog,Cat]
```